# how to print the files name of a folder as file in tabulary way

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, scripting

i have some files in a folder and i want to print thier names in one file.txt in tabulary way like a text not one under one , is there any command for that ?

```
dd1.txt dd2.txt dd3.txt dd5.txt
```

Comment: `ls -l dd*.txt > file.txt`?

Comment: Do you need all on a single line or do you want to break the line as `ls` would ordinarily do? Do you need a specific delimiter between the names to separate them? How do you want to handle names that embed that delimiter?

Comment: all in one single line and separated with space that's all ! . thank you .

Comment: If the filenames do not ever include spaces, `echo * > file.txt` might be enough.

Comment: `ls -w0 dd*.txt` will **display** as if your terminal was infinitely wide (though with wrapround). However, redirection to a file will behave like `ls -1`.

Comment: Is there a reason for the [tag:awk] tag on the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's no need for recursing down into subdirectories:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' * | paste -d ' ' -s - >other/path/file.txt
```

This would list all the visible filenames from the current directory on a single line in the file `other/path/file.txt`.

I'm choosing to write to a file in some other directory, as writing to `file.txt` in the current directory would make that filename part of the output. Make sure that the output filename is free to use first, obviously.

The `printf` utility is usually a built-in utility in the shell, so it would be able to handle this even though `*` may expand to many thousand names (note that `printf` is *not* a built-in utility in `sh` or `ksh` on OpenBSD though). The utility generates a filename per line, but without interfering with the formatting of the names themselves, which `ls` may be doing under some circumstances.

The `paste` command takes the newline-delimited list of names and puts them on a single line with spaces in-between them.  The delimiter is easily changed using the `-d` option, if needed.

This would not properly handle filename with embedded newline characters, nor would it be possible to extract filenames with embedded spaces from the generated list.

Comment: Note that it would print a line containing a litteral `*` if the current directory contained no visible file (contained only hidden file or was not readable by the current user)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ files=(*)
$ echo "${files[@]}"
dd1.txt dd2.txt dd3.txt dd5.txt
```

Comment: That assumes the first filename is not something  like `-n`, `-neenEn`... and/or that none of the file names contain backslash characters, depending on the `echo`/shell implementation and/or runtime/compilation options. With ksh/zsh, `print -r - "${files[@]}"` (`"${files[@]}"`  is ksh syntax already). With `bash` (and  provided the posix and xpg_echo options are not both on): `echo -nE "${files[@]}"$'\n'`.

Comment: Also note that with some shells and with their default options, that would output `*<newline>` if the current working directory contained no non-hidden file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas all true, thanks for mentioning it. I think it's probably adequate for the OPs needs anyway but we'll see if it turns out otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

To print the names of the non-hidden files in the current directory, sorted lexically, separated by space characters and terminated with a newline character, with the `zsh` shell, you can do:

```
print -r - *(N)
```

Or:

```
echo -E - *(N)
```

With the `fish` shell:

```
set files *; echo -E -- $files
```

With the `ksh93` shell:

```
print -r - ~(N)*
```

With the `yash` shell:

```
(set -o nullglob; ECHO_STYLE=raw echo *)
```

With `bash`, and provided the `posix` and `xpg_echo` options are not both enabled (as it is by default in some deployments of `bash`):

```
(shopt -s nullglob; set -- *; echo -En "$@"$'\n')
```

Or:

POSIXly (so would also work in bash (even when not in POSIX mode) and zsh (but only if in POSIX mode)):

```
set -- [*] *
case "$1$2" in
  ('[*]*') printf '\n';;
  (*) 
    printf %s "$2"
    shift 2
    printf ' %s' "$@"
esac
printf '\n'
```

(bearing in mind that that one may fail in shell implementations where `printf` is not builtin and if there is a large number of files in the current working directory).

Note that all those will print an empty line if the current working directory does not contain non-hidden files or is not readable. In any case, the output will only contain one line if none of the file names contain newline characters.

It may come as a surprise that such a simple task should be so hard to do with standard shells, but here we have to work around a few misdesigns of Unix shells and utilities:

- that `echo` (the command meant to output arguments separated by spaces) is one of the most unportable one and where the standard implementations do more than required in a way that can't easily be disabled.
- that many shells including the POSIX sh specification leave globs unexpanded when  they don't match.
- that `ls`, the command to list files, doesn't have any way to produce that list in a format that is post-processable.
- that lines cannot *contain* any arbitrary sequence of bytes (that's the case of text line representations on most systems, not limited to Unix let alone Unix utilities though).